# Big picture with several smaller ones on the side with subfigure/subfig

Tags: tables, graphics, includegraphics, subfig

I want a solution the problem discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302121/big-picture-with-several-smaller-ones-on-the-side/302138?noredirect=1#comment1255855_302138), but using `subfigure` (or `subfig`) instead of `subcaption`.

The question by @Makers_F was:
I'm trying to achieve an effect like:

```
 _____    ___   ___
|     |  |___| |___|
|     |   ___
|_____|  |___|
```

The solution with subcaptions by @egreg is pasted below, but it doesn't work with `subfigure` or `subfig`.

```
a\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newbox{\bigpicturebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\sbox{\bigpicturebox}{%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
  \scalebox{1}[1.2]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Big picture}
\end{subfigure}
}

\usebox{\bigpicturebox}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\bigpicturebox][s]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}

\vfill

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Small figure}
\end{subfigure}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE uses the `subfig` package. I decided to use this package instead of `subfigure` as this packages was su­per­seded by `sub­fig`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newbox{\bigpicturebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sbox{\bigpicturebox}{%
  \subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-1:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
     }%
}%
\usebox{\bigpicturebox}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\bigpicturebox][b]{.45\textwidth}
\subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-2:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}
     }%
     \hfill
     \subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-3:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}
     }%
\vfill
\subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-4:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}
     }%
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can we add a caption for the whole figure without it saying "table"?

Comment: @user7867665: Replace `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` by `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`.

Comment: Thanks! What is the use of the first `\newbox{\bigpicturebox}`? Everything works without it.

Comment: do you know how I can change the order. Have the big picture on the right and two small ones on the left?

Comment: Got it, just put `\hfill` on the bigger box and put it after the `minipage`