# How to create a 2 by 2 by 1 figure in overleaf

Tags: tables, overleaf

I want to create a grid of figures with this layout:

(a)   (b)

(c)   (d)

(e) <- center

I have no idea on how to achieve this layout,please help.

I want to this figure nearby full-1page

Comment: Welcome. // Well, create a grid and center what's neded ... // What I'm trying to illustrate: the better you support your question with code and may be a sketch, the higher the quality of our answers can be.

Comment: Search this site for "align subfigures".

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222656/how-to-align-multiple-subfigures-in-a-grid ? Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508692/how-to-create-a-2-by-2-by-1-figure?rq=1 ?

Comment: You can try subfigure latex ambient!

Comment: Thank you for all comment! it is very useful. Thank you so much everyone.